# Cannot find module 'streamsearch'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've installed my express application with the package.json file like this:

```
{
  "name": "Project_4_User_Login",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "pug": "*",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "mongoose": "*",
    "connect-flash": "*",
    "express-validator": "*",
    "express-session": "*",
    "express-messages": "*",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-local": "*",
    "passport-http": "*",
    "multer": "*"
  }
}
```

I did add some middleware into the app.js file. When I ran the application for the first time using "npm start" command, it threw up an error 'Cannot find module 'streamsearch''. But actually, I didn't use 'streamsearch'.

After that, I went install 'streamsearch' and received another error. This time, it is 'Cannot find module ./code'
Can anybody help me to figure it out? I'm really confused.

Comment: try deleting all node_modules then `npm install`, it might be a missing dependency

Comment: I did that and here is the error `E:\JS\fasf\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:209
    throw new TypeError('app.use() requires middleware functions');
    ^

TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions`

Comment: Seems there is a dependency missing in your package.json

Comment: Also, `./code` is suggesting that it needs one of your own module. You will probably resolve your issue by searching where is the script `code.js`.